# ASP.NET MVC Windows Authentiaction and DirectoryServices - Get Mail Address of the current user throws an InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication, directoryservices, userprincipal

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 and Windows Authentication.
When I am using VisualStudio everything works fine, but when I deploy my site an exception is thrown.

```
var emailAddress = UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress;
```

**throws:**

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal' to type
>   'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal'.

The rest works fine. Users can authenticate and I can get the users name etc.

EDIT:

I enabled Impersonation on IIS.
Now I get the following exception:

> [DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x80072020): An operations error
>   occurred. ]    System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean
>   throwIfFail) +781    System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
>   +44    System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject() +42    System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection.PopulateList() +29
>   System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection..ctor(DirectoryEntry
>   entry, String propertyName) +119
>   System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection.get_Item(String
>   propertyName) +163
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoLDAPDirectoryInitNoContainer()
>   +535649    System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoDomainInit()
>   +51    System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.Initialize()
>   +141    System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.get_QueryCtx()
>   +42    System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithTypeHelper(PrincipalContext
>   context, Type principalType, Nullable`1 identityType, String
>   identityValue, DateTime refDate) +27
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithType(PrincipalContext
>   context, Type principalType, IdentityType identityType, String
>   identityValue) +146
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext
>   context, IdentityType identityType, String identityValue) +44
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.get_Current()
>   +390    Jericho.MVC.HtmlHelperExtensions.GetUser(HtmlHelper htmlHelper) in
>   C:\Development\Jericho\Jericho.MVC\HtmlHelperExtensions.cs:48

What can I do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set the **IIS Application Pool Identity** to **NetworkService** and use:

```
var identityName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
using (HostingEnvironment.Impersonate())
{
    using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "yourDomain", null, ContextOptions.Negotiate | ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer))
    using (var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, identityName))
    {
        emailAddress = userPrincipal.EmailAddress;
        lastname = userPrincipal.Surname;
        firstname = userPrincipal.GivenName;
    }
}
```